# Extensible code to support different HR rules

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datetime, dependency-injection

Recently, I got challenged to code with following bullet points:

> 1. Extensible code to support different annual leave rules for HR departments
> 2. Maintainable code to add/change the existing rules without any impact on the other clients
> 3. Customizable and configurable code for different clients
> 4. Exception handling and logging to protect the code and also make support easier
> 5. Following design and OOP principles
> 6. Unit testable code

I coded keeping SOLID principle in mind and here is my code. What did I miss? I was not able to get a good score with it. What are the design strategies I am missing?

```
public class EmployeeLeave : ILeaveRequest
    {
        IDataBaseService databaseService;

        public EmployeeLeave(IDataBaseService databaseService)
        {
            this.databaseService = databaseService;
        }


        public void ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime leaveStartDate, int days, string reason, int employeeId)
        {
            try
            {
                var employee = FindEmployee(employeeId);

                if ((DateTime.Now - employee.StartDate).TotalDays <= 90 && !employee.IsMarried)
                    throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");

                if (days > 20)
                    throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");

                var leaveRequest = new EmployeeLeaveDetail();

                leaveRequest.EmployeeId = employeeId;
                leaveRequest.LeaveStartDateTime = leaveStartDate;
                leaveRequest.LeaveEndDateTime = leaveStartDate.AddDays(days);

                SaveLeaveRequest(leaveRequest);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public void SaveLeaveRequest(ILeaveRequestDetail leaveRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                databaseService.ExecuteProcedure("spLocal_InsertIntoEmployees", new List<Parameters>
                {
                   new Parameters {ParameterName="@EmployeeId",
                       ParameterValue =leaveRequest.EmployeeId },

                   new Parameters {ParameterName="@StartDate",
                       ParameterValue =leaveRequest.LeaveStartDateTime },

                   new Parameters {ParameterName="@EndDate",
                       ParameterValue =leaveRequest.LeaveEndDateTime }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public Employee FindEmployee(int employeeId)
        {
            Employee employee = default(Employee);

            try
            {
               

                var sqlReader = databaseService.ExecuteProcedure("spLocal_GetEmployeeFromId", new List<Parameters> { new DBLayer.Parameters {
                ParameterName="@EmployeeId",
                ParameterValue=employeeId
            } });


                using (sqlReader)
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        employee = new Employee
                        {
                            EmployeeId = long.Parse(sqlReader["EmployeId"].ToString()),
                            Name = sqlReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                            LastName = sqlReader["LastName"].ToString(),
                            StartDate = DateTime.Parse(sqlReader["StartDate"].ToString()),
                            Salary = Decimal.Parse(sqlReader["Salary"].ToString()),
                            IsMarried = bool.Parse(sqlReader["Married"].ToString())
                        };

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return employee;

        }
    }
```

And below is my Unit Test.

```
public class AnualLeaveTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void IsMarriedAndGreaterThan90Days()
        {
            //TOdo: Need to check if connection ScopeIdentity returned is same
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());
            leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 6, "", 212);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void IsMarriedAndLessThan90Days()
        {
            //To do: Need to check if connection ScopeIdentity returned is same
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());
            leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 6, "", 454);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void NotMarriedAndGreaterThan90Days()
        {
            //TOdo: Need to check if connection ScopeIdentity returned is same
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());
            leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 6, "", 767);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception),"Invalid leave request.")]
        public void NotMarriedAndLessThan90Days()
        {
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());

            leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 6, "", 645);

            
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "Invalid leave request.")]
        public void LeaveRequestGreaterThan20Days()
        {
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());

            leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 26, "", 645);


        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to read this: [Enterprise Rules Engine](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Enterprise_Rules_Engine). Just fyi. ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> I coded keeping SOLID principle in mind and here is my code. What did I miss?

Let's see...

---

## SRP - Single Responsibility Principle

> A class should have only one reason to change.

Violated. The name `EmployeeLeave` suggests it's a class that just stores some data about an employee-leave but its API says something else - I'm a repository. So what is it?

Your class has two reasons to change:

- request rules
- save the request

## OCP - Open/Closed Principle

> Software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

Violated. You have hard-coded all the stored procedure details although you pass a database abstraction via DI.

The user of the `IDataBaseService` should not know that he's working with a stored procedure or anything else. The user just wants to save his data.

You cannot extend it by using a different storage type. If you remove the stored procedure you break this implementation.

## LSP - Liskov Substitution Principle

> Child classes should never break the parent class' type definitions.

Not relevant.

## ISP - Interface Segregation Principle

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Violated. As a person who creates leave-requests and implements `ILeaveRequest` I need to implement the `SaveLeaveRequest` and `FindEmployee`. I don't need it. I just want to create a new request. I don't want to know how to save it (at least not here).

## DIP - Dependency Inversion Principle

> A. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
>   B. Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

Violated. `SaveLeaveRequest` depends on a low level stored procedure although it uses an abstraction `IDataBaseService`.

---

## Summary

> Extensible code to support different annual leave rules for HR departments

Failed. You need to implement the save/find logic for each leave request. This is a lot of redundant code.

> Maintainable code to add/change the existing rules without any impact on the other clients

Failed. The stored procedure call and its details belong to the repository. The user should not know how it's implemented and currently he needs to exactly know the implementation details to be able to use it.

> Customizable and configurable code for different clients

Partially met. You started with a data layer but reveal to much details about the storage to the outside world.

> Exception handling and logging to protect the code and also make support easier
>   Following design and OOP principles

Failed. The *empty* `catch` is not exception handling. The error messages are not very helpful. They don't help to solve the problem by giving a reason or a hint how to correct it.

> Unit testable code

Partially met. You can inject another data layer but the implementation of the `EmployeeLeave` will break if the new data layer doesn't support the hard-coded stored procedure.

---

## Solution (Example)

The interface is a good start but it is too big and it lacks some vital properties that are part of the `ProcessLeaveRequest` signature but shouldn't be.

The minimal interface should require some basic data and a method to validate this data.

```
interface ILeaveRequest
{
    int EmployeeId { get; }
    DateTime LeaveStartDate { get; }
    int DayCount { get; }
    void Validate();
}
```

You implement it by implementing actually only the `Validate` method any adding any other dependencies via DI if for example you need to check if an employee can still take a leave.

Notice the new exception types and messages that clearly explain why the request isn't valid.

```
class VacationRequest : ILeaveRequest
{
    public VacationRequest(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, int employeeId, DateTime leaveStartDate, int dayCount) {..}
    public int EmployeeId { get; }
    public DateTime LeaveStartDate { get; }
    public int DayCount { get; }
    public void Validate()
    {
        // check if employee has enough vacation days...
        throw new OutOfVacationException("Employee 123 does not have any more vacation.");

        // check if max employees have vacation...      
        throw new MaxEmployeeOnVactaionExceededException("The maximum number of 3 employees on vacation at the same time reached.");
    }
}
```

You can create multiple requests by adding more properties and dependencies for more complex rules - or fewer.

This is just a simple example but in a more complex solution you can have an `ILeaveRequestRule` that you pass via DI to concrete request as a collection of several rules so that you may extend them too. In such a case each rule would throw a meaningful exception explaining the violation. It all depends how dynamic the system is. If you think you might need to change them often then it would probably by the way to go.

```
class EmergencyVacationRequest : ILeaveRequest
{
    public EmergencyVacationRequest(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, int employeeId, DateTime leaveStartDate, int dayCount) {..}
    public int EmployeeId { get; }
    public DateTime LeaveStartDate { get; }
    public int DayCount { get; }
    public void Validate()
    {
        // check if employee has enough vacation days...
        throw new OutOfVacationException("Employee 123 does not have any more vacation.");

        // other rules might not apply here...
    }
}
```

To create all the different leave requests you would write a factory (not included in the example).

---

Finally a simple leave request processor validates each request and saves it in the leave repository.

```
class LeaveRequestProcessor
{
    public LeaveRequestProcessor(ILeaveRepository leaveRepository) {..}

    public void ProcessLeaveRequest(ILeaveRequest leaveRequst)
    {
        leaveRequst.Validate(); // You might want to catch this somewhere an log it.

        leaveRepository.SaveLeave(
            leaveRequst.EmployeeId, 
            leaveRequst.LeaveStartDate, 
            leaveRequst.DayCount
        );
    }
}
```

The leave repository can of course modify various tables so that the leave requests have access to this data if they need to in order to validate their rules.

---

Here are some of the advantages of the new solution:

- You can create new leave requests at any time without breaking anything with whatever logic you want
- You implement only what you really need for a new leave request
- You always know what and why it didn't work
- You are independent of the storage type
- You can test all units by mocking the repositories

---

### Appendix - Exceptions vs ValidationResult

There are various opinions about whether you should use exceptions or validation results for thing like this.

- [Is it a good practice to throw an exception on Validate() methods or better to return bool value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230978/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-an-exception-on-validate-methods-or-better-to-r)
- [Is it a good or bad idea throwing Exceptions when validating data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504302/is-it-a-good-or-bad-idea-throwing-exceptions-when-validating-data)

As a matter of fact I use both patterns. It's sometimes a personal or project preference which one you pick.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but I've got to question creating exceptions like `OutOfVacationException`. Let's pretend that we neglected to catch it, should the entire application crash because an employee is out of vacation time??

Comment: @RubberDuck ;-) of course not but this is not the part of the application that should care about it - it should be seen as library code. IMO the user of the `LeaveRequestProcessor` should catch them and handle them accordingly by either showing some messages (not necessarily the exception message) and/or logging them.

Comment: @RubberDuck but what alternatives do we have? You could create rules for each case and to differentiate between them you'd need to work either with error codes (nasty) or you'd need to check the type of the rule somewhere. Not so pretty either. Those states are rather exceptional and esier to handle with exeptions.

Comment: I have a question regarding the use of `employeeId` vs. the actual instance of `Employee`. I would have passed the employee as an argument to the constructor so inside the request I could directly query it regarding any information I might need. By just handing over the ID I might have to make another trip to the database to get an employee that - most likely - was already retrieved before the request was created. Is there any specific argument for passing the ID / against passing the employee?

Comment: @germi I don't see any reason why it should not be allowed. It depends on the design of the database. If the `Employee` model has all the properties you need to validate the leave-request then it's fine with me. If you however need a database trip to get more information anyway then you may as well just use the employee-id. The parameters should be as simple as possible. This makes testing much easier because you don't have to create complex object for them. For example if the `Employee` model had 30 properties and you use only three for the request then a simpler interface should be used.

Comment: @t3chb0t exceptions are for exceptional behavior. You're talking about using them for expected control flow.

Comment: @RubberDuck the expected flow is that an employee requests his leave with correct data, if he didn't it's an exception. It's not like everyone is expected to put invalid data in their requests only to find out what is correct by receiving exceptions. It's not how it is supposed to work. You want to validate their requests but don't expect the requests to be invalid all the time, they shoudn't.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree @t3chb0t. I see a need for a `ValidationResult`, you don't. That's fine.

Comment: @RubberDuck you're right, I've added an appendinx about it.

Comment: Your proposed solution isn't ideal. Why should a leave request be able to validate itself? You're breaking the Open/Closed principle right there - you have to change the source to change the rules that apply to each type. The caller also has to know which type they're dealing with to know which exceptions might be thrown. I'd say that's pretty close to a LSP violation too.

Comment: @RobH I know it's not ideal and it's a start - that's why I also mentioned (somewhere in the middle) that the next step could/should be creating `LeaveRequestRules` that will validate a request in a more generic and extendible way where you can pass a collection of them to the request. A request contains just three properties, I think it's ok that it can validate itself. Actaully it could be called `LeaveRequestValidator` because a request is nothing more then just three or four values so the name isn't perfect too.

Comment: @RobH Usually you design something like this for several hours, I spent writing it maybe 1.5h ;-) I'm pretty sure people will find more weaknesses. But I assure you, I'm not entirely happy with it too.

Comment: @RobH Do you have a better solution?  Please share.  t3chb0t how would you recommend the error handling?  Just run a try/catch in the method that calls ProcessLeaveRequest?

Comment: @user1477388 [Pawel's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150416/22816) is almost exactly how I'd approach it.

Comment: @RobH He's also throwing exceptions but I too like his suggestions. As I've said earlier. You cannot come up with a perfect soultion of this size in just 2h and I don't claim it was perfect but I still think it's a good start for further iterations and improvements. Your arguments make sense but so do all the others that's why you usually spend days with engineering making the solution better and better each day as you recognize more and more patterns. I bet sooner or later someone will post another example with contracts and aspects and even more DI and IoC and all kind of stuff.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I completely agree with what you're saying. I know that you've only suggested an alternative and aren't making any claim that it's perfect. You've also written a very good and comprehensive answer to the question.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Don't we need to add ILeaveRequest to LeaveRequestProcessor ctor?

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> public class EmployeeLeave : ILeaveRequest
> ...
> var leaveRequest = new EmployeeLeaveDetail();
> ```

This is confusing. Going by name, `ILeaveRequest` implies that the class implementing that interface is a "leave request" (I'm aware that classes don't have an "is a" relationship with interfaces). But then we see an *actual* leave request in the form of an `EmployeeLeaveDetail`. This `EmployeeLeave` class simply processes leave requests. So why does this class implement an interface called `ILeaveRequest` when it's not a request and doesn't implement an interface consistent with what you might expect from a leave request? And for that matter, if `EmployeeLeaveDetail` is a leave request (as per your variable's name), why is it called `EmployeeLeaveDetail` rather than `EmployeeLeaveRequest`? I see you created an interface called `ILeaveRequestDetail`. You should rename that interface to `ILeaveRequest`, and rename the current `ILeaveRequest` to something more accurate.

> ```
> if ((DateTime.Now - employee.StartDate).TotalDays <= 90 && !employee.IsMarried)
>   throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");
>
> if (days > 20)
>   throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");
> ```

What's the significance of 90 and 20? Don't use magic numbers, create well named constants and use those instead.

Also as Heslacher said, don't throw an `Exception`; use one of the more specific types or create your own domain-specific exceptions. And at least say what's wrong, otherwise you're left scratching your head as to which of your (potentially) 20 checks failed when you get an `Exception` and it simply says `Invalid leave request`.

> `public void ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime leaveStartDate, int days, string reason, int employeeId)`

I take some issue with the name of this method, because it's not processing (whatever that means) a "leave request". You have a method right underneath, `SaveLeaveRequest(ILeaveRequestDetail)`, which actually deals with a leave request. `ProcessLeaveRequest` just deals with ints, strings, etc.

What I think should be happening here is you have a method in some class to create a leave request for an employee. That method takes the ints, strings, etc, performs validation, and returns a leave request. You can then call the Save method to save the request.

Also in general you should be using domain constructs more. For example, you're accepting an `int`for the employee id. Why? Surely at this point you should have already constructed your `Employee` - it should be impossible to create a request without selecting which `Employee` to create it for - so when creating a request you can just pass in the `Employee`, which removes the need to look it up and potentially fail on request creation.

> 1. Extensible code to support different annual leave rules for HR
>      departments.
> 2. Maintainable code to add/change the existing rules
>      without any impact on the other clients.

Your rules:

> ```
> public void ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime leaveStartDate, int days, string reason, int employeeId)
> {
>   if ((DateTime.Now - employee.StartDate).TotalDays <= 90 && !employee.IsMarried)
>       throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");
>
>   if (days > 20)
>       throw new Exception("Invalid leave request.");
> ```

In what way does hardcoding the rules into the single method that creates and validates the holiday requests meet those requirements? You completely ignored requirement 1.

---

Overall this class feels like it should be a repository, given all the database work it's doing.

Answer (score 14):

> ```
> catch (Exception)
> {
>
>     throw;
> }
> ```

Well this won't buy you anything but a few more lines of code. Just remove the `try..catch` at all. This construct just let the exception bubble up the call stack like it would if you wouldn't have the `try..catch` at all.

---

### public void ProcessLeaveRequest

- You don't validate all of the given method arguments.
- The `reason` argument isn't used at all.
- You are throwing `Exception` instead of e.g `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which would be the better fit.
- it seems (from the `FindEmployee()` method) that `Employee` is a struct (hint `default(Employee)`) which makes it possible that you add something into your database which doesn't belongs there. Assume you pass an `epmloyeeId` which doesn't exists into the `FindEmployee()` method you would the get a `default(Employee)` back which in the case of a struct would have default property values for `StartDate` and `IsMarried`. If this properties would be seen as valid in your validateion part, you would end up with a `EmployeeLeaveDetail` in your database for an employee which doesn't exist.

---

You should always use braces `{}` although they might be optional. By not using them you are in danger of introducing bugs which are hard to track. I would like to encourage you to always use them. This will help you to make your code less error prone.

This is meant for `if`, `else if` and `else`.

Comment: I always wondered about that...what's the point of wrapping in `try/catch` when I'm only gonna throw it to a higher function?

Comment: @Abdul there is no point in wrapping `try/catch` if all you're doing is throwing higher. Only catch an exception if you're going to do something about it (add information, reclassify it, or handle it).

Answer (score 9):

A lot of useful comments is here but no-one has commented about the usage of `DateTime`.

### EmployeeLeave

> `DateTime.Now - employee.StartDate`

I encourage you to process all the dates as UTC and only convert them to local time when you need to display. Even if you are sue your application will be used in one time-zone you save yourself from a lot of hassle in the future if you dedicated that you need to support timezones. The second one is in tests and I'll get back to that at the end.

Another problem with this class is that it does too much. You are violating the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). This class handles holidays, find employee and validating the correctness of holidays. I think you should split that into several classes each responsible for simple task. You can then inject them into your EmployeeLeave class and only construct the logic by calling specific methods.

```
public EmployeeLeave(IEmployeeLeaveStore employeeLeaveStore, 
                     IEmployeeFinder emploeeFinder, 
                     IHolidayValidator holidayValidator)
{
        if (employeeLeaveStore == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employeeLeaveStore));
        if (employeeFinder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employeeFinder));
        if (holidayValidator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(holidayValidator));

        this.employeeLeaveStore = employeeLeaveStore;
        this.employeeFinder = employeeFinder;
        this.holidayValidator = holidayValidator;
}
```

Each interface here is so-called [role interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) that has only the method(methods) for this particular role. So in above example:

- `IEmployeeLeaveStory` - would only contain method for Saving the employee's leave object
- `IEmployeeFinder` - with one method `Find`
- `IHolidayValidator` - with one method `IsValid`

I would be useful to create single rules for validating the correctness of holidays and then compose an aggregate holiday validator that would only execute `IsValid` on its children. It could look like this:

```
var compositeValidator = new CompositeLeaveValidator(
    new NoMoreThanTwentyDaysValidator(), 
    new MarriedAndEmployedForLessThan3MonthsValidator());
```

You can also create a composition based on employee-type as probably different rules are applicable. It's also a good way to extend with new rules.

Additionally in the constructor we check that all the parameters are not null and in case they are we `Fail fast` which is also a good thing to do.

```
public void ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime leaveStartDate, int days, string reason, int employeeId)
{
    var employee = employeeFinder.Find(employeeId);

   if (!holidayValidator.IsValid(leaveStartDate, days, reason, employee))    
       throw new InvalidHolidayException("Specified holiday is invalid.")

    var leaveRequest = new EmployeeLeaveDetail();

    leaveRequest.EmployeeId = employeeId;
    leaveRequest.LeaveStartDateTime = leaveStartDate;
    leaveRequest.LeaveEndDateTime = leaveStartDate.AddDays(days);

    employeeLeaveStore.Save(leaveRequest);
}
```

I would also like to extract this `EmployeeLeaveDetail` creation to a separate class but that's up to you.

As I've mentioned above - there's also one issue with `DateTime`. This time in Unit Tests.

### UnitTest

Basically due to the fact that you use `DateTime.Now` (or `UtcNow` as you should) in your `ProcessLeaveRequest` that means that every time you run your test for this method you run different tests as the DateTime. The better approach to this would be to create a `SystemTime` as follow.

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

then later in your test you can specify what is the current date-time when the test should execute and do not rely on `DateTime` when the test was run.

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsMarriedAndLessThan90Days()
{
    SystemTime.Now = () => new DateTime(2016,12,20, 0,0,0);
    // do the testing with DateTime fixed on 20th of December 2016.
}
```

You also use this class wherever you need a to get a `DateTime`. This way you are sure that everywhere you use UTC or non-UTC and you are consistent.

Additionally check [Five Common Daylight Saving Time Antipatterns of .NET Developers](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/) as there might be some issues with DST when you do calculations on `DateTime`.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, unit tests should follow the ["Arrange, Act, Assert"](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert)-pattern. Yours only have the "Arrange, Act"-part. You're not asserting anything (with the exception of the one where you're expecting an exception to be thrown).

> ```
> [TestMethod]
> public void IsMarriedAndLessThan90Days()
> {
>     // Arrange
>     EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave(new SQLDatabaseService());
>     // Act
>     leave.ProcessLeaveRequest(DateTime.Now, 6, "", 454);
>     // Assert?
> }
> ```

---

Your unit tests depend on your database. You should try to avoid any external dependencies in your unit tests.

---

Related to the point above: You're testing your functionality with existing users. If anything changes in your database (someone marries, the startdate is more than 90 days ago, ...) you have to rewrite your tests. You should explicitly construct your `Employees` in your test cases so they don't change and someone else can easily see what's going on.

---

In my opinion your `EmployeeLeaveRequest` knows to much about how it's going to be saved. Your `IDatabaseService` interface should have methods like `void SaveLeaveRequest(ILeaveRequest request)` where you just hand over your request and let it handle all the SQL or whatever it needs to save the requests. Similar with `FindEmployee`. It should not be the responsibility of the `EmployeeLeaveRequest` to retrieve the employee record from a database.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awesome explanation. I just see one more extensible point by using strategies here, i.e. if the different types of processing can happen based employment categories like Permanent Employee, Contractors etc.

So here we can use processor strategies for different types of leaves and different categories, which can be return by a factory. And the `ProcessLeaveRequest` can take either strategy interface as input or can make a call to `leaveprocessorfactory` to return the proper strategy.

I hope I am making some sense here.